# Как подключить jQuery Migrate к webpack?

Tags: jquery, webpack

Я подключаю jQuery следующим образом:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    '$': 'jquery',
    'jQuery': 'jquery'
})
```

А как таким же образом через ProvidePlugin подключить jQuery Migrate. Ну или не через `ProvidePlugins`. Просто не хотелось бы подключать эту библиотеку через `import` в каждом файле.

Comment: А у этого есть плагин?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-migrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery migrate подключается таким же образом как jquery

```
 new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    '$': 'jquery',
    'jQuery': 'jquery',
    'jquery-migrate': 'jquery-migrate'

 })
```